# How to create a coverage map in Google Maps V3?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a coverage map like the map that appears when you try to use Streetview (see below). What is the best way to go about creating such a map. (assuming that i already have my data in lat/lng points).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into how Google does it and wound up doing the same way.

Google creates a layer of tiles for the coverage map and then displays them on top of the map. (If this becomes a popular question, I'll expand here, please leave a comment)

You can see what i came up with at http://rider.cyclistsroadmap.com

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding overlays of polygons.

Have you tried looking at the [Google Maps API Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=libraries#polygons_v3) code samples ?

Comment: I was thinking of the polygons but that seems like some pretty intense math that I would have to figure out. The Google Maps API Playground is good but unfortunately its all V2

Comment: @paullb : Updated link to point to Google API v3 code samples.

Comment: I managedt o do it to a reasonable extent with an overlay, thanks!

Comment: May I ask for more detail paul? I'm trying to implement a similar map and also have a lot of gps(lat/lng) points. Maybe what was the scale per point? things like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can now create coverage maps like this in Google maps without having to use the API. Just login to your Google account and go to https://maps.google.com

Then click the "My Places" button near the top, then click "Maps" just below that. Finally click "Create Map" and you're on your way. I recommend the interactive tutorial, it will have you making your coverage map in a couple minutes.

When you're done, you can share the map by clicking the chain "link" button in the sidebar and either share the URL or embed the map in a website.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard way to do this through the v3 API, now.

```
var svCoverageLayer = new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
svCoverageLayer.setMap(yourMap);
```